# How to connect Oracle 18c server using oracle 10g server

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-administration, oracle18c

While connecting Oracle 18c using oracle 10g I am getting error like
"ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception".
I can able to connect "SQL DEVELOPER" but not able to connect "Command prompt"

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, see [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

Even if you set `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_...` the connection will most likely fail with another error.

[image]

Comment: Yep. To connect to an 18c server, the client side of the connection must be at least 11.2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spuss/check-for-sqlnet-allowed-logon-version-parameter-behavior.html#GUID-433E0DB9-026E-4322-A8FF-BA0E108AB28B) says:

> Connections to Oracle Database from clients earlier than release 10g fail with the error ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol.

> Starting with Oracle Database 18c, the default value for the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` parameter changes from 11 in Oracle Database 12c (12.2) to 12 in Oracle Database 18c. The use of this parameter is deprecated.

> `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION` is now replaced with the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER` and `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT` parameters. If you have not explicitly set the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER` parameter in the upgraded database, then connections from clients earlier than release 10g fail with the error ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol.

See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In 18c the default minimum version has been changed from 11 to 12 and `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION`  is deprecated and replaced with `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER` and `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT`

set

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=10 
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=10
```

in your sqlnet.ora and reload listener `lsnrctl reload`